# SSRSReport printing service - Invalid report definition error occurs randomly and will only work again after restarting the service

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I have a background service written in C# that picks up print jobs, executes an SSRS report (Using Microsoft.Reporting.Winforms.dll) with a given parameter, and prints the result.

95% of the time this service works fine. However, every so often, at seemingly random intervals (anywhere between a few hours and a few days), the execution of the SSRS reports (that have worked previously with no issues) will start failing with the error 'An error occurred during local report processing.'.

Upon further inspection, this error has an internal error of DefinitionInvalidException, which in turn has an inner exception of ReportPublishingException.

I am releasing any usage of the SSRS classes between each execution, however, once this error has occurred, I am not able to execute any reports (due to the same errors) until I restart the service.

I can run these reports with the same parameters manually, and they work fine. The reports that are failing within the service will have worked minutes before.

Any idea what could be causing this issue?